# Configuring Laravel 3 in localhost

Tags: laravel, localhost, laravel-3

I need to work with my website, made with Laravel 3, in the localhost. I am using a Xampp server, but i don't know which steps I should take in order to get it working, I can't see nothing right know. Somebody could tell me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you should copy the laravel downloaded files in C:\xampp\htdocs\

then you should go with your browser to

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

and see what you got there..